# Difference between "clock off" and "clock out"

Tags: meaning, word-difference

Is there any difference between "clock off", and "clock out"? Wiktionary gives virtually identical definitions for the two ([clock off](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clock_off), [clock out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clock_out))

It's being used in the context of someone paying by the ten-minute chunk for a service they're receiving.

Comment: It must be regional. As an American, I have always heard "clock out" (and "click in") but never "clock off".  I suspect that British, Canadian, Australian, Indian or other English speakers may have a different experience/perception.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock click or clock in?

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is the place in which they are used:

- **Clock out**: This is used by Americans
- **Clock off**: This is used by the British

On the whole, there is no difference in meaning as both of their origins come from the time clock systems.

They're generally used colloquially, for example:

> What time do you clock off? We could go down to the pub later.
>
> I think I might clock out early today...I don't feel very well.